# How to make column-count fill rows first in css3?

Tags: css

I am using (column-count:4) in css3 to fit 9 images in 4 columns (the thing that is thought here: http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/)

but in my case, 9 images just fit 3 columns (3 in each column) and the last column in empty! how can I make it to fill the rows at first?

Comment: Can you show us what you did?

Comment: Your request is not logical...you can't use the concept of "rows" when you're telling the broswer to display the content is columns.

Answer (score 0):

`column-fill: balance` is supposed to do what you want, but that doesn't seem to work in actual browsers.

Maybe multicol isn't the right tool for you. Depending on exactly what you're trying to do, maybe flexbox, or just inline-block might cut it?

http://jsbin.com/nobosu/1/edit?css,output

Maybe this comes a little closer to what you were trying to do:
http://jsbin.com/nobosu/edit?html,css,output

Without specifics, it is a bit hard to know what to prescribe.